# How to reset XSD's element value type and save attribute?

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to set in `XSD` that `Parameter` to have value only from type `XML`

If i replace this:

```
 <xs:element name="Parameter">
   <xs:complexType mixed="true">
     <xs:attribute name="Name" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
   </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

with this:

```
<xs:element name="Parameter">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I loose the `Name` attribute... How to set value to be only valid `XML` and to save attribute `Name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the attribute definition after the sequence element.

```
<xs:element name="Parameter">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```